# Node/Express doesn't update the data model correctly

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

I have followed this [Tutorial](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/10/01/creating-a-restful-api-tutorial-with-nodejs-and-mongodb/) for creating a restful Api with Nodejs and Mongo. It works fine except a few problems. 
My Player model is

```
var player = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
email: String,
score: String
});
```

When I try to post data through Postman extension on Chrome/Firefox, I cannot post the data. The response is the following

```
"__v":0,"_id":"54fed7cf5dde9b1c1e90ed6c"}
```

However, if I make the request through terminal with

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:3000/players -d 'name=ronaldo&email=ronaldo@com&score=232'
```

it works fine.

In addition to this, when try to post or get an Ajax request, I keep getting CORS error even though I added

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
});
```

I also tried to use cors middleware but no luck.
The server is running at http://92.222.36.106:3000/players for temporarily testing purposes. Feel free to use Postman to post data.

Comment: Can you show us your /players endpoint code? Your response looks like it's created a player with the `_id` of `54fed7cf5dde9b1c1e90ed6c`

Answer (score 0):

```
set your cross origin request headers properly ,above you are accessing the request from "http://localhost:8888"(set it your domain) .it allows that domain only.Make sure your domain is properly set it or not .

It allows request from any origin 
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');


It allows request from only "http://localhost:8888"
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine. In Postman check that:

- `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`
- body type is set `raw` and `JSON` is selected.
- Here's some sample data:

  {
    "name": "Mariano Rajoy",
    "email": "sobres.manila@pp.com",
    "score": 0
  }

If that doesn't work, here's a working example. Save this to a .json file and import it as a collection:

```
{"id":"d7fd0131-247a-08c0-4c89-5b46712201b8","name":"Players api","timestamp":1425989704352,"requests":[{"collectionId":"d7fd0131-247a-08c0-4c89-5b46712201b8","id":"2c301d19-62e6-6ad5-40bb-0fbec97305be","name":"http://92.222.36.106:3000/players/","description":"","url":"http://92.222.36.106:3000/players/","method":"POST","headers":"Content-Type: application/json\n","data":"{\n  \"name\": \"Mariano Rajoy\",\n  \"email\": \"sobres.manila@pp.com\",\n  \"score\": 0\n}\n","dataMode":"raw","timestamp":0,"responses":[],"version":2}]}
```

(In your code 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is set to 'http://localhost:8888', but i'm assuming you already set it to '*' since i'm using your api with Postman)

**EDIT:**

Tried with a regular ajax request and it didn't work. Apparently you still have`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` set to `"http://localhost:8888"` instead of `"*"` in your code and Postman / Chrome apps can bypass Cross Origin, didn't know that..